# Performance issue full index scan in mysql database

Tags: mysql, database-optimization

I have a database with a table called QuizMatches. The table has the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `QuizMatches` (
  `QuizMatchesGuid` binary(16) NOT NULL,
  `DateStarted` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LatestChanged` datetime NOT NULL,
  `HostFBUserToken` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `GuestFBUserToken` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `ArrayOfQuestionIDs` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersHost` varchar(900) NOT NULL,
  `ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersGuest` varchar(900) NOT NULL,
  `MatchFinished` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `Category` varchar(45) NOT NULL,
  `JsonQuestions` varchar(4000) NOT NULL DEFAULT '[]',
  `DateFinished` datetime NOT NULL,
  `LatestPushSentDate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`QuizMatchesGuid`),
  KEY `HostFBUserTokenIX` (`HostFBUserToken`),
  KEY `GuestFBUserTokenIX` (`GuestFBUserToken`),
  KEY `MatchFinishedIX` (`MatchFinished`),
  KEY `LatestChangedIX` (`LatestChanged`),
  KEY `LatestPushSentDateIX` (`LatestPushSentDate`),
  KEY `DateFinishedIX` (`LatestChanged`,`HostFBUserToken`,`GuestFBUserToken`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

There is a large number of rows in this table and it is heavily used by multiple clients especially queries like the following are executed:

```
SELECT HEX(QuizMatchesGuid) AS QuizMatchesGuid, DateStarted,
    LatestChanged, HostFBUserToken, GuestFBUserToken,
    ArrayOfQuestionIDs, ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersHost,
    ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersGuest, JsonQuestions
FROM CrystalDBQuiz.QuizMatches
ORDER BY LatestChanged DESC
LIMIT 10
```

The main problem seem to be that the database performs a full index scan. I have tried with different combinations of indexes but to no success.

If I run EXPLAIN on the above SELECT query I receive the following:

```
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: 'QuizMatches'
         type: index
possible_keys: NULL
          key: 'LatestChangedIX'
      key_len: 8
          ref: NULL
         rows: 10
        Extra:
```

Is there a way I can optimize SELECTS as the above example towards this database table?

[image: Neor profiler screenshot]

Comment: The `SELECT` you show, and its `EXPLAIN`, do not result in a full table scan. The `key` and `rows` output from the `EXPLAIN` command show that it's using an index.

Comment: This explain looks clean to me, it uses LatestChanged index to get sorted rows and ends as soon as 10 of them are found. Why do you think it is bad?

Comment: As I understand it, according to the EXPLAIN it does a full index scan? is that really necessary? Is there any other way to improve this table and query? The mysql server works 100% and that is just if I do around 10 of these selects per second.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `LIMIT` statement for pagination I suggest you to use `LatestChanged` value for this due to ordering. So your query will turn to

```
SELECT HEX(QuizMatchesGuid) AS QuizMatchesGuid, DateStarted, LatestChanged, 
HostFBUserToken, GuestFBUserToken, ArrayOfQuestionIDs,
ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersHost, 
ArrayOfQuestionResponseTimesAndAnswersGuest, JsonQuestions 
FROM CrystalDBQuiz.QuizMatches 
WHERE LatestChanged<[lastValue]
ORDER BY LatestChanged DESC
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: Thanks but it is not for pagination